# Firefox CVE-2015-4495

Tags: firefox, pdf

I recently read that there was a major vulnerability fixed in Firefox: [CVE-2015-4495](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Critical+Firefox+Update+Today/20013/) Which would have affected Linux as well, as there is a PDF viewer for this version, however would it affect you if you weren't using the PDF viewer? Is it only a PDF exploit? Or would it not matter whether or not you were viewing a PDF, and it could be any website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF exploit has included **JS** code, it can only be run if you are viewing the infected document, you can enable **Noscript plugin to block websites to redirect to such document**, such backdoor could be on any Website, it's recommended to read HTML code before you visiting to a Webisite, read info here: http://zneweasy.com/2015/07/05/how-to-read-website-content-without-browserno-hacking-tutorial/, as for PDF exploit, they can be executed only when you open such file, read more here: http://zneweasy.com/2015/07/09/is-pdf-file-backdoor/